# How to clear all contents of textbox when spacebar is pressed? VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm creating a simple typing test program.

I want the space bar to trigger checking if the typed word is correct, then clear the contents of the textbox.

What happens here is the first typed word will work and be counted when the space bar is pressed and the typed word will be cleared, but the space character still remains and so the next typed word will contain a space char and will be read wrong.

I tried interchanging where the `txtInput.Clear()` should be placed but results in the same problem.

```
Private Sub txtInput_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtInput.KeyDown

    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Space Then
        Space()
    End If

End Sub

Public Function Space()

    If txtInput.Text = txtWord.Text Then
        ctr = CInt(txtWord.TextLength)
        charTotal = charTotal + ctr
        lblScore.Text = charTotal.ToString
    End If

    txtInput.Clear()
    txtWord.Text = rdmWord()

End Function
```

Comment: Add `e.SupressKeyPress = True` to prevent the space from getting added.

Answer (score 1):

In `KewDown` `Event` the value of `TextBox` isnot setted yet. So, use `KeyUp` `Event` as the code below shows

```
Private Sub txtInput_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtInput.KeyUp
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Space Then
        Space()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also override [ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey?view=net-5.0) and trap the spacebar there:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Space Then
        If Me.ActiveControl Is txtInput Then
            Space()
            Return True ' suppress space
        End If
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

If you want to allow space or enter, then change to:

```
    If keyData = Keys.Space Or keyData = Keys.Enter Then
```